# Can a website display dynamic data without an XHR request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, server-side-rendering, xbox

Some background info, I have been trying to perform a screen scrape on Xbox.com, specifically I am looking to scrape the available video clips for a user. The information is displayed in a web based way so my thought was that data was being requested from a service. I have been using Fiddler and chromes network debugger to see data coming in, and I can see the activity feed via the debuggers, but the captures section data doesn't load via Xhr.

So my question is how can a website display data to the user that is dynamic and loaded each time without making a javascript service request. Perhaps server-side rendering?

What kind of technologies exist to do such things so that user's cannot directly see where data is coming from.

What benefits if any are gained from doing something like this?

Link to my Xbox Page: [Profile Page](https://account.xbox.com/en-US/Profile?gamerTag=Holy%20Breadstick)

Screenshot of website that doesn't have a matching Xhr request:
[image]

Comment: What is the link that is used? Perhaps it is using websockets - for which you need to examine the frames.

Comment: Would chome list that under the ws section? Because nothing is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some idea :

- Create an iframe, set an URL, get the data from there.
- Use SSE technique (server send chunked response, and to prevent timeout send a "ping" data from time to time)
- build a plugin inserted in the browser that will make a TCP connection to a server and give you event